# Conda Environment

Tags: anaconda, environment, conda

I am trying to create an environment using this https://github.com/mbareera/MuSA/blob/master/MuSA.yml  file but I am getting error below. I am using conda 22.11.1 version. Can anyone help how I can create environment using this iml file?

```
ResolvePackageNotFound: 
  - cftime==1.6.2=py39h7deecbd_0
  - mkl_fft==1.3.1=py39hd3c417c_0
  - libevent==2.1.12=h8f2d780_0
  - libcurl==7.88.1=h91b91d3_0
  - packaging==23.0=py39h06a4308_0
  - ca-certificates==2023.01.10=h06a4308_0
  - dill==0.3.6=py39h06a4308_0
  - libthrift==0.15.0=hcc01f38_0
  - libssh2==1.10.0=h8f2d780_0
  - zstd==1.5.2=ha4553b6_0
  - pyqt==5.15.7=py39h6a678d5_1
  - lz4-c==1.9.4=h6a678d5_0
  - qt-main==5.15.2=h327a75a_7
  - python==3.9.16=h7a1cb2a_2
  - aws-c-event-stream==0.1.6=h2531618_5
  - aws-c-common==0.4.57=he6710b0_1
  - cffi==1.15.1=py39h5eee18b_3
  - mkl==2021.4.0=h06a4308_640
  - libxcb==1.15=h7f8727e_0
  - numba==0.56.4=py39h417a72b_0
  - lcms2==2.12=h3be6417_0
  - numpy-base==1.23.5=py39h31eccc5_0
  - re2==2022.04.01=h295c915_0
  - libgomp==11.2.0=h1234567_1
  - netcdf4==1.6.2=py39h89d13dc_0
  - arrow-cpp==10.0.1=py39h613000e_0
  - statsmodels==0.13.5=py39h7deecbd_1
  - gflags==2.2.2=he6710b0_0
  - bottleneck==1.3.5=py39h7deecbd_0
  - certifi==2022.12.7=py39h06a4308_0
  - glog==0.5.0=h2531618_0
  - ncurses==6.4=h6a678d5_0
  - pysocks==1.7.1=py39h06a4308_0
  - libgfortran-ng==11.2.0=h00389a5_1
  - mkl-service==2.4.0=py39h7f8727e_0
  - lerc==3.0=h295c915_0
  - mpi4py==3.1.4=py39hfc96bbd_0
  - grpc-cpp==1.46.1=h33aed49_1
  - libnghttp2==1.46.0=hce63b2e_0
  - hdf4==4.2.13=h3ca952b_2
  - mkl_random==1.2.2=py39h51133e4_0
  - tornado==6.2=py39h5eee18b_0
  - gst-plugins-base==1.14.1=h6a678d5_1
  - fontconfig==2.14.1=h52c9d5c_1
  - libbrotlienc==1.0.9=h5eee18b_7
  - scikit-learn==1.2.1=py39h6a678d5_0
  - ipython==8.10.0=py39h06a4308_0
  - llvmlite==0.39.1=py39he621ea3_0
  - traitlets==5.7.1=py39h06a4308_0
  - libxml2==2.9.14=h74e7548_0
  - ld_impl_linux-64==2.38=h1181459_1
  - freetype==2.12.1=h4a9f257_0
  - icu==58.2=he6710b0_3
  - qt-webengine==5.15.9=hd2b0992_4
  - sqlite==3.41.1=h5eee18b_0
  - jedi==0.18.1=py39h06a4308_1
  - pyarrow==10.0.1=py39h992f0b0_0
  - brotli-bin==1.0.9=h5eee18b_7
  - pyopenssl==23.0.0=py39h06a4308_0
  - libwebp-base==1.2.4=h5eee18b_1
  - libboost==1.73.0=h28710b8_12
  - dbus==1.13.18=hb2f20db_0
  - gstreamer==1.14.1=h5eee18b_1
  - scipy==1.10.0=py39h14f4228_1
  - aws-sdk-cpp==1.8.185=hce553d0_0
  - nspr==4.33=h295c915_0
  - libprotobuf==3.20.3=he621ea3_0
  - qtwebkit==5.212=h4eab89a_4
  - patsy==0.5.3=py39h06a4308_0
  - curl==7.88.1=h5eee18b_0
  - pillow==9.4.0=py39h6a678d5_0
  - brotli==1.0.9=h5eee18b_7
  - libllvm10==10.0.1=hbcb73fb_5
  - giflib==5.2.1=h5eee18b_3
  - multiprocess==0.70.14=py39h06a4308_0
  - urllib3==1.26.14=py39h06a4308_0
  - joblib==1.1.1=py39h06a4308_0
  - wheel==0.38.4=py39h06a4308_0
  - kiwisolver==1.4.4=py39h6a678d5_0
  - matplotlib-base==3.7.1=py39h417a72b_1
  - intel-openmp==2021.4.0=h06a4308_3561
  - prompt-toolkit==3.0.36=py39h06a4308_0
  - hdf5==1.10.6=h3ffc7dd_1
  - libpq==12.9=h16c4e8d_3
  - boost-cpp==1.73.0=h7f8727e_12
  - xz==5.2.10=h5eee18b_1
  - zipp==3.11.0=py39h06a4308_0
  - nss==3.74=h0370c37_0
  - contourpy==1.0.5=py39hdb19cb5_0
  - pytz==2022.7=py39h06a4308_0
  - matplotlib-inline==0.1.6=py39h06a4308_0
  - libbrotlicommon==1.0.9=h5eee18b_7
  - zlib==1.2.13=h5eee18b_0
  - c-ares==1.19.0=h5eee18b_0
  - jpeg==9e=h5eee18b_1
  - orc==1.7.4=hb3bc3d3_1
  - libdeflate==1.17=h5eee18b_0
  - matplotlib==3.7.1=py39h06a4308_1
  - tbb==2021.7.0=hdb19cb5_0
  - libuuid==1.41.5=h5eee18b_0
  - libzip==1.8.0=h5cef20c_0
  - glib==2.69.1=he621ea3_2
  - numexpr==2.8.4=py39he184ba9_0
  - pcre==8.45=h295c915_0
  - bzip2==1.0.8=h7b6447c_0
  - _openmp_mutex==5.1=1_gnu
  - expat==2.4.9=h6a678d5_0
  - abseil-cpp==20211102.0=hd4dd3e8_0
  - libev==4.33=h7f8727e_1
  - brotlipy==0.7.0=py39h27cfd23_1003
  - libxslt==1.1.35=h4e12654_0
  - tk==8.6.12=h1ccaba5_0
  - cryptography==39.0.1=py39h9ce1e76_0
  - pyparsing==3.0.9=py39h06a4308_0
  - libwebp==1.2.4=h11a3e52_1
  - libbrotlidec==1.0.9=h5eee18b_7
  - pyqt5-sip==12.11.0=py39h6a678d5_1
  - openssl==1.1.1t=h7f8727e_0
  - pip==23.0.1=py39h06a4308_0
  - libffi==3.4.2=h6a678d5_6
  - libllvm11==11.1.0=h9e868ea_6
  - libxkbcommon==1.0.1=hfa300c1_0
  - setuptools==65.6.3=py39h06a4308_0
  - numpy==1.23.5=py39h14f4228_0
  - krb5==1.19.4=h568e23c_0
  - libnetcdf==4.8.1=h8322cc2_2
  - libgcc-ng==11.2.0=h1234567_1
  - utf8proc==2.6.1=h27cfd23_0
  - libclang==10.0.1=default_hb85057a_2
  - sip==6.6.2=py39h6a678d5_0
  - idna==3.4=py39h06a4308_0
  - requests==2.28.1=py39h06a4308_1
  - aws-checksums==0.1.9=he6710b0_0
  - libstdcxx-ng==11.2.0=h1234567_1
  - snappy==1.1.9=h295c915_0
  - libpng==1.6.39=h5eee18b_0
  - pandas==1.5.3=py39h417a72b_0
  - libedit==3.1.20221030=h5eee18b_0
  - libgfortran5==11.2.0=h1234567_1
  - ply==3.11=py39h06a4308_0
  - libtiff==4.5.0=h6a678d5_2
  - readline==8.2=h5eee18b_0
```

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** Please edit your question to include the version of the Ubuntu OS that you're using, as that will help in diagnosing your issue. That said, based on your question, it's unclear to me how the Ubuntu OS is a factor in contributing to your issue. You might better be served in reviewing [the official Conda documentation for installation on Ubuntu](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/linux.html).